# Eloquent belongsToMany relation with additional conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I need to fetch all models which a user belongs to and additionally **all** models  `where private = 0` (From all other users)

I already tried it with two merged seperate queries - but with this method there are duplicated items.

Also this approach doesn't work:

```
$this->belongsToMany('ManiacTwister\Models\Collection', 'collection_members')
->orWhere("private", "=", 0);
```

Comment: Your solution will definitely work as long as you want to check private field on the related model's table, but you may need to use 'relatedTableName.private','=',0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the 'private' field is on your collection_members table then setup a pivot field using 'private' and then search by the pivot

```
$this->belongsToMany('ManiacTwister\Models\Collection', 'collection_members')
        ->orWherePivot('private','0');
```

or you could

```
$this->belongsToMany('ManiacTwister\Models\Collection', 'collection_members')
       ->orWhere("collection_members.private", "=", 0);
```

Both should work the first one is table agnostic (i.e. it links to the model) but the second one will be faster

Comment: Edit. I believe you have an extra " ( " on the call to belongsToMany in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

Take off the `orWhere()` on your model and eager load it.

```
$member = Member::where('id', '1')->has(array('collections' => function($q)
{
    $q->where('private', '0');
}))->get()->first();

foreach($member->collections as $collection) {
     echo $collection->name;
}
```

Comment: `Method name must be a string` (has() doesn't take an array as first argument). Also i guess this would return all non-private Models which belongs to the given user but i want all non-private pastes from all users.