# Additional conditions on a belongsToMany relation on the intermediate table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, has-and-belongs-to-many, eloquent-relationship

When using the `belongsToMany` relation in Laravel Eloquent, is it possible to add additional conditions for the intermediate table? Currently, the inserts are duplicating and I am just trying to understand how to fix it.

Here is the relation

**Models/Order.php**

```php
public function addresses(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(CustomerAddress::class)
            ->withPivot('address_type')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Here is how I save the data to the intermediate table

```
$tenantOrder-addresses()->attach($customerAddress->id, [
                'address_type' => 'billing'
            ]);
```

Do I need to do anything else to prevent the duplicates? Below is the example of showing the duplicates. The combination being `customer_address_id, order_id, address_type`.

I did take a look at [Eloquent belongsToMany relation with additional conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153798/eloquent-belongstomany-relation-with-additional-conditions), but this doesn't help with the resolution.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your issue there. Instead second row in that table example, you want to update first row with different `address_type`?

Comment: If you notice, 1-1-billing repeats again in the third row. I am trying to figure out how to prevent this duplication.

Comment: Again, if your intention is to update pivot field instead adding new row, try with `sync` method instead `attach`.

Comment: ok, let me give this a try and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: You could create a pivot model for that pivot table and use updateOrCreate. Alternatively you’ll need to put a unique MySQL rule on the columns which cannot be duplicated. Might be good to do both.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to prevent duplicate on pivot table, can add composite keys on pivot table migrations

Something like this

```php
...
$table->primary(['customer_address_id', 'order_id', 'address_type']);
```

That will prevent adding new row if the customer, order, and address type in a same value.

Here's a [test](https://web.tinkerwell.app/#/snippets/767bd4b0-c02c-41bb-b218-d85d8353b0c6)

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#available-index-types)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `syncWithoutDetaching`. It helps `attach` without duplicated record.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations